# Is there any other fql function like "me()"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is `me()` the only `function` I can put in a FQL request?

If not, can you give the Facebook doc page where I can find other functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use several other functions in a FQL request.

From [FQL Technical Guide Doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/)

```
Other functions that are available are now(), strlen(), substr() and strpos().
```

Comment: the section is so small that i missed it! Thanks!